# urban Airship notification on/off

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, urbanairship.com

I implemented urban airship and send test message to iPhone . everything is working fine. now I want user to control the notification either on to receive notifications or off to disable in setting.

how can I control this while the code in appdelegate ? and which part of Urban airship implementation is controlling the notification display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to turn off notification
Use the following code

```
[UAPush shared].pushEnabled=NO;
```

For receiving the notification again, write the following code

```
[UAPush shared].pushEnabled=YES;
```

Comment: could you please help me .. How can I test urban airship notification .. I did test correctly in my device , but I try to test in other device (my friend other pc and other iphone) .. we installed the app , but device token is null .. What shall I do ?

Comment: @Wain could you help me in above question?

Answer (score 2):

Urban airship doesn't control the display, just the registration. The display is done by iOS.

You can change the registration using the `updateRegistration` method of `UAPush`.

Comment: thank you for your reply.. ok, this can be control by move to setting and setup the APNS as wanted .. do you know if I can control this too programmatically ?

Comment: The `updateRegistration` method can be called both the enable and disable push notifications from being sent to the device.

Comment: I thought about using tags as add/ remove and updateRegistration .. and always send notification to the tagged tokens only.. Is there better solution?

Comment: Personal preference now, but from a privacy point of view you probably shouldn't be sending the user token info if they set an option to disable notifications.

Comment: this is exactly what I want from the beginning ..but I couldn't get how to do it? using udateRegistration?? where shall I do that ? ..   I appreciate your help

Comment: Yes, `udateRegistration` will do that (check the docs) and you should call it when the user changes their preferences (and not register when the app is started if the user has said not to).